# Point within multiple spheres

Tags: algorithm, math, position

[image]

The above graphic is meant to more efficiently display my problem than I would ever hope to be able to explain with words.

As you can see, there is an n-number ( 3 in this case ) of spheres ( displayed as circles for simplicity ) of varying sizes, and a point ( the red one ) which technically belongs to all 3 of them at once.

However, a point can only belong to a single sphere at any one time.

What I'm trying to find is an efficient algorithm, which will allow me to determine which of these spheres the point *actually* belongs to. The end result, I'm hoping, will look a little something like this:

[image]

Here, I've used the radial lines to "clip" the circles in the graphic where appropriate, and it is clear now that the red dot belongs to the large left-most circle.

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Are you looking for a [power diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram)?

Comment: @NicoSchertler It appears I may be. This was one of the issues, I had no idea what this problem was called, or what to even google for. This will make for an interesting read, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to test a single point or one to subdivide the space and define all the regions?

Comment: @samgak Looking for one to test a single point, apologies if that wasn't made clear in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a point lies within a circle, define the circle by its center and a radius and check if the distance of the point to the center is less than the radius.

To find which circle a point belongs to (in the manner indicated by your diagram), compute the power of the point as the distance of the point to the circle center point, squared, minus the square of the circle radius:

power = distance<sup>2</sup> - radius<sup>2</sup>

If the result is less than 0, it's inside that circle. It belongs to the circle with the smallest power.

Comment: Would that not then result in something which looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/X9sLph7.png)?

As in, the point will end up belonging to the smallest circle, which is not the point after all

Comment: No, it wouldn't, that's what you would get if you used the minimum distance (without dividing by the radius).

Comment: I disagree with this. Using relative distances, the point even more clearly belongs to the smallest circle.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a comment.

If I am right, the loci of the points equidistant to two spheres in the reduced sense (proportionally to the radius) are themselves on a sphere (that can degenerate to a plane).

The diagram is as below:

[image]

Comment: I see what you're saying, using the proportional distance to the center wouldn't result in _exactly_ the same sort of result as I have displayed on my graphic. That's good to know, though for my purposes this would be good enough :)